# How can I get the list of Twitter user names by their location?

Tags: r, api, twitter, get, location

I've been using the twitter REST API and need to access the list of Twitter users by their location. I've looked through the GET request lists here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup, but I can't seem to find the GET request that would accomplish what I need. I am working with R and have looked at TwitteR but didn't find anything useful. and I am new to using APIs so any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make a request, first load httr, then call GET() with a url:
library(httr)
r <- GET("http:enter your url here")

Answer (score 0):

you can use [users/search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search) and pass locations as a parameter with url

You need to change url to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Toronto&page=1&count=3

Comment: Can you be more specific? This is the URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&page=1&count=3. For example, if I want the users in Toronto. How can I code that in R?

Comment: You need to change url to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Toronto&page=1&count=3